# How to make search bar responsive using CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design

I have a search bar at my website page http://positivelynuts.co.uk/blog/

It shows only for half width on mobile devices and looks small. How can I make it responsive using CSS so that it takes the fullwidth on mobiles and comes above the pagination page links ?

```
<div class="blogpage_search" style="width: 50%; float:left;">
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="http://positivelynuts.co.uk">
<div class="search-form">
<input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s">
<input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search">
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: `<div class="blogpage_search" style="width: 100%; float:left;">`

Comment: use bootstrap if you want i help you to make a search box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first take the `style="width: 50%; float:left;"` element out and add this to your css file:

```
.blogpage_search {
   width: 50%;
   float: left;
   margin-top: 7px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   .blogpage_search {
      float: none;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 10px auto;
   }
}
```

That should do the trick! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

use `width:100%;`

```
<div class="blogpage_search" style="width: 100%; float:left;">
```